# Script or Ruby gem for finding every keyword a website domain ranks for in Google

Tags: keyword, google-search, keyword-search

Not sure if this is a long shot but I'm going to go for it. I am looking for either a script, or ruby gem that can find every keyword that a website is ranking for in Google Search.  It should return the keyword, and the webpage URL that is found in search. Any help would be greatly appreciated.